# Remove $ and comma sign from a column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, replace

I'm new for programming. Now I'm learning web scraping and I'm trying to extract the tesla's revenue table from the website and create a Dataframe. But I want to remove the "$" and "," sign in the revenue column. here's my code:

```
tesla_revenue=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","Revenue"])
for row in tables[table_index].tbody.find_all('tr'):
    col=row.find_all('td')
    if col!=[]:
        date=col[0].text
        revenue=col[1].string
        
        tesla_revenue=tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date,"Revenue":revenue},ignore_index=True)
        tesla_revenue['Revenue']=tesla_revenue['Revenue'].replace({'$','',',',''},regex=True)
tesla_revenue
```

The output I got was like:
[image: the output table]

I tried the code like:
tesla_revenue['Revenue']=tesla_revenue['Revenue'].str.replace({'$','',',',''},regex=True)

Then I got an error message. How can I remove the $ and comma sign in the Revenue column?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing them before you add to the dataframe.

```
tesla_revenue=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","Revenue"])
for row in tables[table_index].tbody.find_all('tr'):
    col=row.find_all('td')
    if col!=[]:
        date=col[0].text
        revenue=col[1].string[1:].replace(',', '')
        
        tesla_revenue=tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date,"Revenue":revenue},ignore_index=True)
        tesla_revenue['Revenue']=tesla_revenue['Revenue'].replace({'$','',',',''},regex=True)
tesla_revenue
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. May I have the code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
original_string = "!(Hell@o)"
characters_to_remove = "!()@"

new_string = original_string
for character in characters_to_remove:
  new_string = new_string.replace(character, "")

print(new_string)
```

Since, you're beginner. It can help you to understand